# 502 truncated server while trying to access Soap api in Magento via Google app script

Tags: php, magento, soap, google-apps-script, soap-client

With the help of following php code, I can access api and successfully retrieve data from the website.

```
    <?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.mydomain.com/api/soap?wsdl');    
$action = "sales_order.list";
$since = date("2014-06-23", strtotime('-1 day'));
$filters = array('updated_at' => array('from' => $since));    
$session = $client->login('name', 'api_key');
$arr = $client->call($session,$action,array($filters));
print_r($arr);
```

And this is the same code in Google App Script:

```
   function myNewFunc() {     

          var client = SoapService.wsdl('http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/soap/index/');
          Logger.log(client.getServiceNames());
          var magService = client.getService("MagentoService");
          Logger.log(magService.getOperationNames());
          var session = magService.login('name','api_key');
          var action = "sales_order.list";      
          var d1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "2014-06-22");
          var d2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "2014-06-23");
          var dates = [d1,d2];
          Logger.log(magService.call(session, action, Array(dates)));
}
```

which gives something like this:

> Request failed for http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/api/soap/index/
>   returned code 502. Truncated server response 502 Bad Gateway

I can access the url in the browser. I thought there may be a problem with 'Array(dates)' but even if I call an 'action' which doesn't require a date, it produces same error. Any solutions?
Note: I am an absolute beginner. Bear with me.

Comment: Syntax for Utilities.formatDate() is wrong, should be Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");  probably not the main issue but worth changing :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas But its working fine. If i run Logger.log(dates), it shows  [2014-06-24, 2014-06-25] an array of dates, which is required, I guess.